# iOS: Accessing MySQL DB directly?

Tags: iphone, mysql, ios

While googling this issue, I found this: [MySQL Connector written by Karl Kraft](http://www.karlkraft.com/index.php/2011/06/07/mysql-for-iphone-and-osx-version-2-0/). Has anyone tried it successfully? Is there any better libraries for this issue? Any tutorials?

I know I can access DBs through REST Web Services, but I have no PHP Programmers to configure it for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will be so much happier if you just write a REST service. It is incredibly easy, especially on Rails. See [this link](http://gavinmorrice.com/blog/posts/21-building-a-rest-api-in-rails-3).

In 6 minutes he shows you how to create a RESTful service that supports creating, updating, and deleting.